# 'select not in' query with subquery selecting varchar(30)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and trying to create a query for following scenario using SQL Server.

I have a table named `GenericLabels` containing list of all the labels (`varchar(30)`) that can be used. They are used in table called `UserDeviceStatus`. I want list of labels which are in `GenericLabels` but not used in `UserDeviceStatus` for a given `UserId`.

I have created following query

```
select label 
from GenericLabels 
where not exists (select customlabel from UserDeviceStatus where userid = 40)
```

This query returns empty result

Here is the output with individual queries.

```
select label from GenericLabels
```

returns

```
Aux1
Aux2
Aux3
Aux4
Aux5
Aux6
```

and

```
select customlabel from userdevicestatus where userid = 40
```

returns

```
Aux2
Aux3
```

I want following result

```
Aux1
Aux4
Aux5 
Aux6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 select label from GenericLabels where label not in (select customlabel from UserDeviceStatus where userid = 40)
```

Comment: The use of "not in" is very intuitive, but often very slow.  Less intuitive, but quicker, is "where in (select field from table minus select field from table where something)"

Comment: I've heard that `not in` is slower, but I thought modern optimizers generally produce the same execution plan whether you use `exists` or `not in / in` ?

Comment: When in doubt, test it.  Mind you, much of my work is on a database engine that is more than 5 years old.  That's not exactly modern.

Comment: The performance is not the problem but 'not in' can give surprising results if the column is nullable. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 4):

You have to link on label and customlabel:

```
select label from GenericLabels 
where not exists (
    select 1 from UserDeviceStatus 
    where customlabel = label 
    and userid = 40
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT customlabel from userdevicesstatus where userid != 40
```

This should give you the wanted result.